# Change ld-linux location

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

I have find out that to load libraries, a executable first opens `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. All the functionality regarding loading shared libraries (search in many paths, using rpath, etc) will work only after `ld-linux` is loaded, because it is `ld-linux` that implements these functionality.

It seemed to me that `ld-linux.so` location is hardcoded in executable (invoking `strings` on my executable reinforces this theory). My problem is that in my linux distribution, the compiler (g++) sets the `ld-linux` location to `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. While on Ubuntu (which is more popular) it is located at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

I was wondering if I can make my executable looks for `ld-linux.so` at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`(which is also present in my distro as a symbolic link).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to your `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: is it possible supply a path relative to the binary?

Comment: I doubt that's a good idea even if it works, because your binary will not work if placed into the wrong directory.

Comment: that's exactly what I am trying to solve: with absolute path it works only in specific location, meanwhile I want the whole directory of binaries to be relocatable, i.e. ship a zip and let the user unpack wherever s/he wants.

Comment: BTW, ld-linux.so is somehow coupled with libc6.so – one has to ship both or none, otherwise the binary crashes. So for the sake of backward and forward compatibility all need to be shipped.

Answer (score 1):

patchelf can be used to change the path to ld-linux interpreter.